# Zend Gdata StructuredQuery for empty cells

Tags: zend-framework, gdata, gdata-api, google-data-api

How do I do structured query for empty cell.

I tried like this:

```
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_ListQuery();
$query->setSpreadsheetKey($spreadsheetKey);
$query->setWorksheetId($worksheetId);
$query->setSpreadsheetQuery('name="" and lastname=John');
$listFeed = $spreadsheetService->getListFeed($query);
```

But every time i do this i get: `Parse error: Invalid token encountered`

I have tried with single quotes, double quotes... nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in `Zend_Uri_Http` class in method `getQueryArray`

```
public function getQueryAsArray()
{
    $query = $this->getQuery();

    $queryArray = array();
    if ($query !== false) {
        parse_str($query, $queryArray);
    }

    return $queryArray;
}
```

PHP was set with `magic_quotes_gpc = On` which caused structured query to be escaped in a wrog way.